Update only specific elements
I created a component that constantly receiving data from server. This data is a collection of Virtual Machine properties (such as free memory, hard disk space, etc.). In 80% of responses the data is the same (nothing changed between previous response and this response) but the whole collection of objects are send again.
On Angular side the component receive the response and replace (?) the current one like this:
vmCollection = signal(new VmCollection());

this.server.Subscribe({
  next: (data) => {
    this.vmCollection.set(data)
    ...
    ...
 }

on HTML template I do:
<div *ngFor="let vm of vmCollection()">
  <vmInfo [vm]="vm"></vmInfo>
</div>

this logic cause the destroying and re-building the <vmInfo> component each time new data is received.
What I want to do is to update only some elements on existing data. For example if Virtual Machine name is changed then update only 'name' not destroy -> re-create the whole component.
Is there any best practice on how to do that ?
There's a slight chance that new VM will be added and then the app need to re-create the whole list of <vmInfo> elements again - that's ok, but usually only some fields are changed (not the whole VM information object)
I do know on how to calculate the difference with existing data but not sure about technique on how not to re-build the whole <vmInfo> component when data is changed

To improve the performance, you can either add a trackBy expression to your *ngFor, or better use the @for block from control flow which requires a track expression. However I don't think it will fully achieve the desired result.

Create on server side a hash from all VM  properties and on the client side in the loop compare the new hash with the old hash and if is different... something has changed and only than bind the data to .
